# Haskell: profiler output not complete?

Tags: haskell, profiling

I'm building a project that stores words into a dictionary (using the library `dawg`), and when compiled with -fprof-auto, the profiler doesn't tell me that most of the time is spent in functions and CAFs from dawg modules.

The code (also using conduit, but it's pretty straightforward) is:

```
import Data.DAWG.Static as D
import qualified Data.DAWG.Dynamic as DD
import Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators as C
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.List (isSuffixOf)
import Control.Monad


insertEntry dawg word =
  DD.insertWith (+) (T.unpack word) 1 dawg

isWhitespace x = x `elem` [' ', '.', '\n', '\'']

appendFileToDDAWG dawg fp =
  C.sourceFile fp $= C.decodeUtf8
  $= C.splitOnUnboundedE isWhitespace
  $$ C.foldl insertEntry dawg 

loadDirToDAWG :: FilePath -> IO (DAWG Char () Int)
loadDirToDAWG dir = runResourceT $ do
  d <- C.sourceDirectoryDeep True dir
       $= C.filter (".txt" `isSuffixOf`)
       $$ C.foldM appendFileToDDAWG DD.empty
  return $ D.freeze d

main = do d <- loadDirToDAWG some_directory
          mapM_ print $ D.assocs d
```

Running with +RTS -p shows me most of the time is spent in insertEntry (which is normal):

```
COST CENTRE          MODULE                      no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                 MAIN                        211           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                Main                        423           0    2.3    1.7    99.9  100.0
  loadDirToDAWG      Mymodule.BuildDAWG          425           0    1.9    1.0    97.6   98.2
   appendFileToDDAWG Mymodule.BuildDAWG          427          74    8.0    5.1    95.7   97.2
    insertEntry      Mymodule.BuildDAWG          430       71366   86.5   92.1    86.5   92.1
    [...]
CAF                  Data.DAWG.Static            418           0    0.1    0.0     0.1    0.0
CAF                  Data.DAWG.Trans.Map         412           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

But it doesn't tell me that the time is actually spent inside the `Data.DAWG.Dynamic` module. Which is weird because it shows the `Data.DAWG.Static` module, so it's able to "detect" some modules from dawg but not all of them, and especially not the one where most of the work is done.

After downloading dawg, modifying its .cabal file so it's compiled with `-fprof-auto-top`, and rebuilding everything I get a larger profiler output that shows all inner functions of `Data.DAWG.Dynamic` and seems ok. But I don't want the full detail (I'm not profiling dawg, just my code) and I just want to be sure that the time is spent in dawg and not in my code (or else it means my code has a problem).

So why in the first case was the `Data.DAWG.Dynamic` module not shown?
Is there something I'm missing regarding how GHC handles profiling?

Comment: It seems to me that `Data.DAWG.Static` is shown because it corresponds to a CAF. In general, modules from existing packages wouldn't (and shouldn't - how could they!) be shown, if you haven't built the corresponding package with profiling enabled. If you want to profile library code you'll have to rebuild it (and its dependencies, I believe) with profiling enabled.

Comment: Every library I use is built with profiling enabled. Though dawg is _not_ built by default with "-fprof-auto-top". So it enables profiling but it doesn't add SCCs on every function.
And why doesn't ```Data.DAWG.Dynamic``` correspond to a CAF, then?